# Rust equivalent code for this C++ mutex code

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex

The mutex and threads examples on
the internet are not good as I am not able to find how to lock a block of code using a mutex to lock a method.

```cpp
// mutex example
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex

std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section

void print_block (int n, char c) {
  // critical section (exclusive access to std::cout signaled by locking mtx):
  mtx.lock();
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { std::cout << c; }
  std::cout << '\n';
  mtx.unlock();
}

int main ()
{
  std::thread th1 (print_block,50,'*');
  std::thread th2 (print_block,50,'$');

  th1.join();
  th2.join();

  return 0;
}
```

What is similar Rust code for this C++ snippet? Locking loops and printing as in Rust example the mutex must be of that type such as

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![1u32, 2, 3]));

    for i in 0..3 {
        let data = data.clone();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut data = data.lock().unwrap();
            data[i] += 1;
        });
    }
    thread::sleep_ms(50);
}
```

Comment: What will be rust similar code for this c++ snippet, locking loops and printing as in rust example the mutex must of that type such as
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![1u32, 2, 3]));

    for i in 0..3 {
        let data = data.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut data = data.lock().unwrap();
            data[i] += 1;
        });
    }

    thread::sleep_ms(50);
}

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61578416/edit) your question to add the question.

Comment: @idclev463035818 done

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How can I lock the internals of my Rust data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36039917/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Are you looking for [`Stdout::lock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdout.html#method.lock)?

Answer (score -2):

I have written this similar code. Is it fine or can it be written in a better way?

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let mtx = Arc::new(Mutex::new(""));

    let mtx1 = mtx.clone();

    let mtx2 = mtx.clone();

    let n = 50;

    let th1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        mtx1.lock().unwrap();

        printData(n, "*".to_string());
    });

    let th2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        mtx2.lock().unwrap();

        printData(n, "$".to_string());
    });

    th1.join();
    th2.join();
}

fn printData(n: u32, c: String) {
    let mut str_val: String = "".to_string();

    for i in 0..n {
        str_val.push_str(&c);
    }

    println!("{}", str_val);
}
```

Comment: You can use `()` aka the unit type for when you need a lock that doesn't protect anything.

Comment: for reviews of working code there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/